# How to set the Referer of HttpRequest in windows store app?

Tags: c#, httprequest, windows-store-apps

I want to download some images from a website, but it must send the request with 'referer'.
the code like this:

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(imgUrl);
 CookieContainer cc = new CookieContainer();
 request.CookieContainer = cc;
 request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.56 Safari/536.5";
 request.Referer = "http://www.xxxxx.com/xxx/xxx/list_78542.html";
 request.CookieContainer = cc;
 HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
 using (Stream stream = myResponse.GetResponseStream())
 ...
```

however, when i want to do it in windows store apps, it has not the property 'Referer' in WebRequest, I try to use this(as below) to set the 'UserAgent' and 'Referer'

```
    request.Headers["UserAgent"] = UserAgent;
    request.Headers["Referer"] = Referer;
```

but it raise an error **"The 'Referer' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method."**

What should i do, help me, please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **Windows.Web.Http** namespace instead of **System.Net** as described here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn440594.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Very simple:

myHttpWebRequest.Referer="http://www.microsoft.com";

Comment: This answer does not solve the issue for Windows Store apps or universal portable class libraries for that matter. It only solves the problem for regular C# applications.